# human verification, recaptcha impossible to read

Tags: support

Has anyone else see captcha verification when trying to post answers? Sometimes I'll get a recaptcha. Posting using Tor.

[This](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/433/80) question required captcha verification. Just be because of 3 links.

This doesn't make any sense to me. Never any posts of me were flagged spam, deleted, etc. And seems like my account has some reputation already, not that I care, but that should help the system figuring out I am not a spam bot.

Quite often these recaptcha over Tor are so obscure, impossible to read. Not being able to flawlessly use Tor here may put off lots of users. Kinda defeats the purpose of this community.

Any way for stackexchange to lower the anti spam measures for this community? Especially for users with reputation that doesn't make sense. And for new users, moderator manually confirming a question would be better than some impossible to read google recaptcha.

Answer (score 3):

The higher frequency is probably due to the IP address that the system is seeing when you log in using Tor.

The problem of unreadable captchas does exist network wide. One of the workarounds is to keep changing the captcha you have got, till you get a readable one.

Its unlikely that anti-spam measures will be reduced. It is not feasible for every question to be reviewed before it gets posted, moreover, it is near impossible for every answer to get reviewed before posting (by mods alone).

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that determine whether we show a captcha or not. I am sure you understand the need not to publicly disclose the Secret Sauce™ in order to be a tiny bit more annoying for the spammers.

As far as I can tell there is no factor that would penalize users of this site in particular, it must be something you are doing that makes your activity look suspicious.

Regarding the unreadability of the CAPTCHA -- we are aware of the issue, you can chime in [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have never got captcha though I have multiple accounts over few years on Stack Exchange. I do not connect over Tor and my IP addresses are not probably shared with other users contributing to Stack Exchange. It is probable that captcha can be provoked by changing IP addresses. See comments on [Captcha for verification anymore, how can they defend against bots?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186380/220244).

Other factor is frequency of edits:

- [Too much spam validation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178656/220244)
- [Please stop asking me a captcha with over 500 reputation. I am human](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81012/220244)
- [I am not a robot!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143455/220244)